# How to combine "positive" with "negative" polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have 2 polygone classes (1 and 2). Inside the polygons are holes (white). Now  I want to combine them with the polygon in witch the holes are. Understand? Sorry for that bad english...

[image]

The white holes have to be green or blue, like the sourrounding polygon. Any idea? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think it is called "remove the holes". I could have told you how to do it with MapInfo, but don't know qgis.

Comment: Looking at the number of holes, I assume you want an automated method?

Comment: right! ;) this is just 10% of the whole map

Answer (score 1):

If you have a polygon deliminating your study area extent I would use the Difference tool (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference) to create an inverse set of polygons then union this with your layer above, then dissolve.

In ArcGIS, you would undertake an Erase operation, union and then dissolve.

Alternatively, you could convert to raster and reclassify.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Munday gives a solution.  Alternatively you could code this as a Python script using GDAL/OGR and iterate over your polygons, pullout their geometry, drop all the interior ring (i.e. just take the first linear ring per polygon) and save to a new shapefile.